# Detecting python coroutine called as subroutine

Tags: python, coroutine

Let's say I have a bunch of coroutines. These coroutines should be called using `yield from`. How can I detect I made a mistake and directly called the coroutine like a subroutine ?

Here is an example code :

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def A(msg):
    print(msg)
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

@asyncio.coroutine
def B():
    while True :
        yield from A('1')
        A('2')
        yield from A('3')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(B())
```

And the output :

```
1
3
1
3
1
3
...
```

Calling coroutine like subroutine does nothing, but does not raise exception or block the event loop, so the failure mode is very quiet.

Comment: Coroutines? Are you sure this is python? Python has functions.

Comment: @muddyfish: Python has generator functions that can be used as coroutines, in that the language supports delegation, sending messages and throwing exceptions in generator functions.

Comment: @muddyfish, [do you want to know more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)?

Comment: @downvoters Please don't downvote this question without understanding it. Python does have coroutine (of sorts), and they will become more prominent with the advent of [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/).

Comment: I hope an example code for those out there downvoting without a comment will help there change their mind. The unclear aspect is now gone.

Answer (score 4):

I added a check_iterator function to your code.  If you decorate your coroutine with this function, it will print information out if your coroutine is ever directly called and is not accessed using `__iter__`.  Depending on your actual code, you may need to make a more complete implementation and wrap `__next__` as well.  That would probably be somewhat lower-performance, though.

```
import asyncio
import functools

class IterWrap(object):
    def __init__(self, f, *args, **kwds):
        self.iterated = False
        self.info = [f, args, kwds]
        self.f = f(*args, **kwds)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.iterated = True
        return iter(self.f)

    def __del__(self):
        if not self.iterated:
            print("Did not yield: %s" % self.info)

def check_iterator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        return IterWrap(f, *args, **kwds)
    return wrapper

@check_iterator
@asyncio.coroutine
def A(msg):
    print(msg)
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

@asyncio.coroutine
def B():
    while True :
        yield from A('1')
        A('2')
        yield from A('3')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(B())
```

The results of running this on Python 3.4 are:

```
1
Did not yield: [<function A at 0xb6e3189c>, ('2',), {}]
3
1
Did not yield: [<function A at 0xb6e3189c>, ('2',), {}]
3
1
Did not yield: [<function A at 0xb6e3189c>, ('2',), {}]
3
1
Did not yield: [<function A at 0xb6e3189c>, ('2',), {}]
3
```

Comment: Wow, this is a testimony to the power of python !